# Map a stored procedure to an Entity object and its child objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Within EF4, it's pretty easy to map a stored procedure into an entity.  I create the stored proc, Add it to the model, then do a Function Import and specify the parent entity.

Now, the rub comes in that I want my stored proc to do "eager loading" of the children entities.

In effect, I have a table Parents and a table Children, with a one to many relationship between them.  I'd like my stored proc to return all Parents that match a criteria and all Children of those parents, distributed into the entity model as one would imagine.

How is this accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean that you want your stored procedure to return multiple result sets, you may want to have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580202/can-entity-framework-deal-with-multiple-result-sets-each-from-joined-tables-fro).

The basic gist is that this isn't supported as an out-of-the-box feature, but there's an extension to EF that evidently makes this possible.